# Delete and Edit buttons won't function

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am creating a crud application with a list of students an their grades I am trying to do a delete and edit method on the front end and also when I click edit their should be a pop up form that comes up and when I click delete their should be a message saying that You want to delete this

```js
$('#studentUpdate').click(function(a) {
  a.preventDefault();
  let update = {
    _id: $($("#updateForm")[0].int).val(),
    role_num: $($("#updateForm")[0].role_num).val(),
    first_name: $($("#updateForm")[0].first_name).val(),
    last_name: $($("#updateForm")[0].last_name).val(),
    marks: $($("#updateForm")[0].marks).val(),
  }

  $("#updateForm").trigger("reset");
  $("#updateForm").toggle();

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3200/students/updateStudent",
    method: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: update,
  }).always(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    showStudents();
  });
});

$("body").on('click', 'deleteStudent', function(a) {
a.preventDefault();
var student_id = $(this).data('student_id');
console.log(a);
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:3200/students/deleteStudent" + student_id,
  method: 'DELETE',
  dataType: 'json',
}).always(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  showStudents();
  confirm("You want to delete this");
});
});
});

function showStudents() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3200/students",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      $('#students').empty();
      $.each(response, function(i, student) {
        const text = "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + student._id + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + student.role_num + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + student.first_name + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + student.last_name + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + student.marks + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger deleteStudent\"  data-studentid=" + student._id + ">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
          "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger edit-student' data-toggle='modal' data-target1='#exampleModal2' data-studentid=" + student._id + ">Edit</button></td>";
        $("#students").append(text);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editStudentModal2" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel2">Update Student</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="updateForm">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="id" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">ID</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="student_id">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="role_num" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Role Number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="role_num">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="last_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="marks" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Marks</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Marks">
            </div>
          </div>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">End</button>
          <button id="studentUpdate" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=#exampleModal2>Update Student
                          </button>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I do not know what I am missing here could I have had a wrong id label or it could be something wrong in my jquery. Also when ever I click the edit and delete button nothing happens

Comment: `deleteStudent` is class you miss (`.`) on click.

Comment: @Shree ok got that thanks but also I do not know why my update is not working or edit button

Comment: Where is your edit click function ?

Comment: @Shree it is above the delete student function

Comment: I only see `studentUpdate` not `edit-student` ?  where is `edit-student` click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tag called `<deleteStudent/>`, select it using class selector like `.deleteStudent`

```js
$('#studentUpdate').click(function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();
    let update = {
      _id: $($("#updateForm")[0].int).val(),
      role_num: $($("#updateForm")[0].role_num).val(),
      first_name: $($("#updateForm")[0].first_name).val(),
      last_name: $($("#updateForm")[0].last_name).val(),
      marks: $($("#updateForm")[0].marks).val(),
    }

    $("#updateForm").trigger("reset");
    $("#updateForm").toggle();

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:3200/students/updateStudent",
      method: 'PUT',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: update,
    }).always(function(data){
          console.log(data);
          showStudents();
     });
 });

  $(document).on('click', '.deleteStudent', function(a) { //Please look closely here
    a.preventDefault();
    var student_id = $(this).data('student_id');
    console.log(a);
    $.ajax({
       url: "http://localhost:3200/students/deleteStudent" + student_id,
      method: 'DELETE',
      dataType: 'json',
   }).always(function(data){
           console.log(data);
           showStudents();
              confirm("You want to delete this");
   });
});

function showStudents() {
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:3200/students",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    $('#students').empty();
    $.each(response, function(i, student) {
      const text = "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + student._id + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + student.role_num + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + student.first_name + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + student.last_name + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + student.marks + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + "<button button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger deleteStudent\"  data-studentid=" + student._id + ">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
        "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger edit-student' data-toggle='modal' data-target1='#exampleModal2' data-studentid=" + student._id + ">Edit</button></td>";
      $("#students").append(text);
    });
  }
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editStudentModal2"
       aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel2">Update Student</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="updateForm">
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="id" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">ID</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="student_id">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="role_num" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Role Number</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="role_num">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">First Name</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="last_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="marks" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Marks</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Marks">
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">End</button>
                      <button id="studentUpdate" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                              data-target=#exampleModal2>Update Student
                      </button>
                  </form>

              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```